# MySQL slow running query - Need help with tuning

Tags: mysql-8.0, aws-aurora

I am using the Aurora MySQL Serverless V2 database and facing an issue with the below query taking longer. In the end, I have listed different approaches that I tried to fix this.
The table has around 10M rows.
By increasing the InnoDB buffer pool size from 2 GB to 4 GB, the number of recorded slow queries was reduced. I see from the plan that it is trying to create a temporary table.
Can you please share if this can be done any better?

```
CREATE TABLE 'VCont' (
  'id' varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  'version' int NOT NULL,
  'colId' bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  'conId' bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  'aId' bigint NOT NULL,
  'oId' bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  'startTime' datetime NOT NULL,
  'endTime' datetime NOT NULL,
  'trType' varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  'cc' varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  'price' int DEFAULT NULL,
  'starRating' varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  'isAdult' char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  'statId' int DEFAULT NULL,
  'parId' int DEFAULT NULL,
  'vLocal' varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  'createDate' datetime NOT NULL,
  'deviceType' varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  'conSupPId' int NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  'brandingparId' int NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  'categories' varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  'collectionType' varchar(128) DEFAULT '-1',
  'duration' int NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  'linearStartTime' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  'isAvailableTimeLocal' tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  'ccCreateDateTime' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  'ccUpdateDateTime' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  UNIQUE KEY 'uidx_ct_as_of_vl_tt_dt' ('conId','aId','oId','vLocal','trType','deviceType'),
  KEY 'idx_pt' ('parId'),
  KEY 'idx_ct_pt_vl' ('conId','parId','vLocal'),
  KEY 'idx_cl_pt_vl' ('colId','parId','vLocal'),
  KEY 'idx_csp' ('conSupPId'),
  KEY 'idx_of' ('oId'),
  KEY 'idx_pt_et' ('parId','endTime'),
  KEY 'idx_pt_st_et' ('parId','startTime','endTime')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Here is the query and the explain plan:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT DISTINCT
    brandingparId
FROM
    VCont
WHERE
    parId IN (4576 , 1005006,
        1006190,
        1005040,
        3455)
        AND (conSupPId = - 1
        OR conSupPId IN (4576 , 1005006,1006190,1446173,1445040,3455))
        AND (statId IS NULL OR statId = 0
        OR statId IN (427517051 , 2304,427517048,427517055,427517053,427517063,4109251,427571587))
        AND (trType != 'vod'
          OR vLocal = 'cableco11_510')
        AND (trType != 'ipVod'
          OR vLocal = 'cableco11_510'
          OR vLocal IS NULL)
        AND colId = 165719466
        AND ((isAvailableTimeLocal = 0
            AND startTime <= '2023-09-19 14:16:19'
            AND endTime >= '2023-09-19 14:16:19')
          OR (isAvailableTimeLocal = 1
            AND startTime <= '2023-09-19 07:16:19'
            AND endTime >= '2023-09-19 07:16:19'));
```

Plan details:

```
-> Table scan on <temporary>  (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=4 loops=1)
    -> Temporary table with deduplication  (cost=1087.27 rows=9) (actual time=1586.611..1586.611 rows=4 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (((VCont.conSupPId = <cache>(-(1))) or (VCont.conSupPId in (4576 , 1005006,1006190,1446173, 1445040,3455))) and ((VCont.statId is null) or (VCont.statId = 0) or (VCont.statId in (427517051 , 2304,
        427517048,427517055,427517053,427517063,4109251,427571587))) and ((VCont.trType <> 'vod') or (VCont.vLocal = 'cableco11_510')) and ((VCont.trType <> 'ipVod') or (VCont.vLocal = 'cableco11_510') or (VCont.vLocal is null)) and (((VCont.isAvailableTimeLocal = 0) and (VCont.startTime <= TIMESTAMP'2023-09-19 14:16:19') and (VCont.endTime >= TIMESTAMP'2023-09-19 14:16:19')) or ((VCont.isAvailableTimeLocal = 1) and (VCont.startTime <= TIMESTAMP'2023-09-19 07:16:19') and (VCont.endTime >= TIMESTAMP'2023-09-19 07:16:19'))))  (cost=1087.27 rows=9) (actual time=16.046..1584.080 rows=852 loops=1)
            -> Index range scan on VCont using idx_cl_pt_vl, with index condition: ((VCont.colId = 317847606) and (VCont.parId in (4576,1005006,1006190,1006173,4547,1006011,1006010,4809,1006004,1009011,1005040,3455)))  (cost=1087.27 rows=958) (actual time=16.035..1582.760 rows=951 loops=1)
```

Approaches tried:

1. Delete the existing indexes and recreate the indexes as below:

```
ALTER TABLE VCont ADD INDEX alt_idx_pt_ct_csp_tt_vl (parId, conId, conSupPId, trType, vLocal);

ALTER TABLE VCont ADD INDEX alt_idx_pt_cl_csp_tt_vl (parId, colId, conSupPId, trType, vLocal);
```

I could still see the performance issue after the index changes.

2. I tried to rewrite the query to optimally use the index by grouping the fields in the index and applying the criteria below on the returned rows. It didn't help.
3. Performance metrics were enabled on this schema and could see the query has many temp tables created. performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest.SUM_CREATED_TEMP_TABLES is a big value compared to other queries.

Comment: Enabled profiling on the query and see that executing took over 1 sec.

Comment: At a quick glance it just seems like an overly complicated predicate that should be split out into multiple queries and simplified (even from a business logic perspective) if possible. What is the count of rows for just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VCont WHERE parId IN (4576 , 1005006, 1006190, 1005040, 3455)` ?

Comment: @J.D. the above query resulted in 2260536 rows.